# Rounding in jinja2 brackets

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I guess just generally I'm curious about what operations are allowable in jinja2 brackets, e.g. what I'm trying to do is perform an operation on embedded data like so:

```
{{ round(255*(mileage['chevy'] - mileage['ford']))/1000 }}
```

This throws the error on traceback:

> UndefinedError: 'round' is undefined

Similarly when I try to use 'abs' in a bracketed jinja block, I get an Undefined error--even though they're both standard lib functions. Is there some way to perform this operation during template-rendering, rather than before passing the data?

Comment: In general, you want to do calculations in your program code, not in your template. I'm not sure what you think Jinja2's brackets do, but what they don't do is allow you to embed python code in your templates.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The jinja2 templating language is different from the python language. In jinja2, operation on values are often done during filters : `{{ something | operation }}`. You can find a [list of filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters) in the jinja2 documentation.

For example, to [round](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#round), you can do :

```
{{ 42.55|round }}
```

This will display "42" on the web page. A `abs` filter exist in the same way.

Please note that these filters can only be used to alter values before display, and can be used for calculations. Calculations shouldn't be done in the template anyway.

Comment: +1. Just to add to this, the available objects and functions are injected through the [context](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#the-context) which contains only a few special items by default.

Comment: Thanks, I jumped into using python template libraries thinking it was like PHP or Java server pages. This answers my question.

Comment: "Calculations shouldn't be done in the template anyway." <- This is poor advice. Take for example a table of data, where the numbers need to be displayed in different ways in multiple columns.

Comment: Well, if the transformation needed to display the columns is non-trivial, they are actually different numbers, different data. It's the role of the controller/view (depending on how you call it) to provide that data to the template.

Comment: If the transformation is simple, however (eg a partial value divided by a total value for the purpose of showing a percent), doing it in the controller is wasteful bloat that should sensibly be in the view.

Comment: `{{ 42.55|round }}` This will display "42". No! First, it should round to 43. But then, this function somehow returns a float, so it will return `43.0`. Which is *not* what `round(42.55)` returns in python. :-/ For this, you'd need `{{ 42.55 | round | int }}`.

Answer (score 4):

According to Jinja Docs [[round]](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.round)

```
{{ 42.55|round }}
```

will returns `float` so result will be `43.0`. Iif you need to specify precision use:

```
{{ 42.55321|round(2) }}
```

will return `42.55`, also you can choose method of rounding, eg. `round(2, 'ceil')`

also when performing some math operations take it into brackets like:

```
{{ (x*y/z)|round(2) }}
```

Comment: If you want to remove the trailing `.0`, you can call `{{ 42.55 | round | int }}`.

Answer (score -1):

If you really need to use the parentheses style, you can pass the required functions as rendering parameters.

For example, this small code:

```py
from jinja2 import Environment, BaseLoader

mytemplate = '{{ round(3.7) }}'
result = Environment(loader=BaseLoader).from_string(mytemplate).render(round=round)
print(result)
```

prints:

```sh
4
```

You can also pass all functions from a module:

```py
from jinja2 import Environment, BaseLoader
import math
from inspect import getmembers

mytemplate = '{{ fabs(sin(-pi/3)) }}'
result = Environment(loader=BaseLoader).from_string(mytemplate).render(getmembers(math))
print(result)
```

which prints:

```sh
0.8660254037844386
```