# Jinja2 round filter not rounding

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, template-engine

I have the following code in my template:

```
data: [{% for deet in deets %} {{ deet.value*100|round(1) }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %} {% endfor %}]
```

I am expecting data rounded to 1 decimal place.  However, when I view the page or source, this is the output I'm getting:

```
data: [ 44.2765833818,  44.2765833818,  44.2765833818,  44.2765833818,  44.2765833818,  44.2765833818,  44.2765833818,  44.2765833818,  44.2765833818,  44.2765833818 ]
```

This is not rounded to 1 decimal place.  It runs without a template error or anything, but produces incorrect output. My understanding [from the documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#round), and even [a related stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675653/rounding-in-jinja2-brackets), are that my format should work.  What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like your code is rounding `100` instead of the **product** of `deet.value*100`. You should probably prefer to do the multiplication in your code, and not in the template.

Comment: Gotcha, I take your point, but I switched to 100*deet.value | round(3) and that solved it for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Didn't realize the filter operator had precedence over multiplication!

Following up on bernie's comment, I switched

```
{{ deet.value*100|round(1) }}
```

to

```
{{ 100*deet.value|round(1) }}
```

which solved the problem.  I agree the processing should happen in the code elsewhere, and that would be better practice.

Comment: This obviously doesn't work for division. In that case, Jinja is incapable of rounding the result. I'm not in agreement with the idea that the maths should be done in a controller rather than view. That's a bad smell masked as a good smell.

Comment: For a division, put parenthesis around: `{{ (deet.value / 2) | round() }}`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66802920/ansible-strange-rounding-behaviour

Answer (score 55):

You can put parens around the value that you want to round. (This works for division as well, contrary to what @sobri wrote.)

```
{{ (deet.value/100)|round }}
```

NOTE: `round` returns a `float` so if you really want the `int` you have to pass the value through that filter as well.

```
{{ (deet.value/100)|round|int }}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
{{ (deet.value*100)|round(1) }}
```

If we didn't put parenthesis, round will do only to 100 not to the result.

Answer (score 3):

I ran across this... needed int(mem_total / 4) in jinja.  I solved it by making it two operations:

```
{% set LS_HEAP_SIZE = grains['mem_total'] / 4 %}
{% set LS_HEAP_SIZE = LS_HEAP_SIZE | round | int %}
```

Answer (score 2):

If filter operator has precedence, then you should use round(3) instead of round(1) in "{{ 100*deet.value|round(1) }}"