# Ansible - strange rounding behaviour

Tags: ansible, rounding

I want to calculate memory sizes and need rounding functionality - but my ansible does not behave as documentation claims it should. This is my playbook:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "need to configure swap for {{ ansible_memtotal_mb }} megabytes -> {{ ansible_memtotal_mb/1024 }} GB -> the file will have {{ ansible_memtotal_mb / 1024.0 | round(2, 'floor') }} gigabytes"
```

And this is the output I get:

```
"msg": "need to configure swap for 1987 megabytes -> 1.9404296875 GB -> the file will have 1.9404296875 gigabytes"
```

I'd expect the last value to be 1.94 GB. Why is the round filter not respected at all?

Comment: Probably need to add parantheses: `(ansible_memtotal_mb / 1024.0) | round(2, 'floor')`. Otherwise only `1024.0` will get rounded to 2 decimal digits (which does nothing).

Comment: Just for a quick confirmation with a one liner you can run in your terminal: `ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg=\"{{ 123546 / 1024.0 | round(2, 'floor') }} vs {{ (123546 / 1024.0) | round(2, 'floor') }}\""` => `"msg": "120.650390625 vs 120.65"`

Comment: Parenteses did the trick! So the issue was just operator precedence - what a bummer!
Thank you for pointing out, Jan. If you post this as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jan provided the correct answer:

> Probably need to add parantheses: (ansible_memtotal_mb / 1024.0) |
> round(2, 'floor'). Otherwise only 1024.0 will get rounded to 2 decimal
> digits (which does nothing).

I just put it here to mark this question as answered and thus for others easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

Round accepts two arguments. The first argument is the precision and the second argument is the rounding method to use.
When no arguments are specified, the precision is 0 and the method is common, like this.

---

[jzhang@centos9 playbooks]$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ (123546 / 1024.0) | round(0, 'common') }}"
localhost | SUCCESS => {
"msg": "121.0"
}

---

The precision argument tells round how many decimals to round. The second argument is the rounding method, which can be common (either round up or down), ceil (always round up)
or floor (always round down).

---

[jzhang@centos9 playbooks]$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ (123546 / 1024.0) | round(2, 'floor') }}"
localhost | SUCCESS => {
"msg": "120.65"
}

---

[jzhang@centos9 playbooks]$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ (123546 / 1024.0) | round(2, 'ceil') }}"
localhost | SUCCESS => {
"msg": "120.66"
}

---

[jzhang@centos9 playbooks]$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ (123546 / 1024.0) | round(2, 'common') }}"
localhost | SUCCESS => {
"msg": "120.65"
}